# Angular directive with $timeout not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple directive that searches the DOM to find matching inputs and hide them (Customer wants to be able to dinamically hide soke fields). The directive Works fine in Chrome but not in IE11. `ng-show` and `ng-if` are a valid alternatives, but the application has thousands of fields, so it would be very time consuming.

I use the $timeout(function,0) in able for the dom to be ready (I understand it is equivalent to a $(document).ready in JQuery).

The directive is as follows:

```
angular.module("ngEnter", [])
    .directive("hideFields", ['$timeout', function (timer) {
        return {
            scope: { permisos: '=permisos' },
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
                var hideElements = function () {
                    if (scope.permisos) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < scope.permisos.length; i++) {
                            var element = document.getElementById(scope.permisos[i]);
                            while (true) {
                                element = element.parentElement;
                                if (angular.element(element).hasClass('form-group'))
                                    break;
                            }
                            element.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                }
                timer(hideElements,0);

            }

        };
    }]);
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$timeout` is not equivalent to `$(document).ready`. `$timeout` is a wrapper for `window.setTimeout`.

Comment: The `while (true)` loop looks really sketchy.

Comment: @georgeawg you are totally right, but is there another way for the dom to be Ready before executing the directive? And the loop can be improved, but it is a quick and dirty tryout. The main issue is that it does not work in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

My good friend Jay helped me solve the problem. Incresing the timeout value to 500 did the trick.

Original line: `timer(hideElements,0);`

Changed line: `timer(hideElements,500);`

Somehow in a strange manner, the angular execution pipeline is different in IE than it is in Chrome, so setting the $timeout to 0, did not do the trick in IE. Anyways, hope it saves same time to others in the future.